# linq2sql select Not working - .NET 4.5.2

Tags: select, linq-to-sql

Here is my code

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable() 
dt.Column.Add("ID");
dt.Column.Add("Name");
// Fill some data using loop
var result = (from t in dt select t)
```

The error im getting is

Error   CS1660  Cannot convert query expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

I dont know what is wrong in this. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you get that particular error message, but the problem is that DataTable is not enumerable and hence you need to use

```
var result = (from t in dt.AsEnumerable() select t);
```

You also need to include a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll